# cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Threading.Task.Task<bool>'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, async-await

I am creating a Service (and a interface) in .NET Core MVC. In this Service I am trying to create this method that will be used in some of my controllers and should return a Boolean.

it seems like I need to async/await it, but when I do, it shows red ramen with the following error message:

> 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accesible
> method 'GetAwaiter' acceptiong a first argument of type 'bool' could
> be found (are you using a directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's the Method from my service:

```
public async Task<bool> MethodThatDoThings(double firstName, int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var enroll =  _context.SkipEnrollments.Where(x => x.firstName== firstName)
                                                   .Select(y => y.id);

            bool elegible = new();                                                                  


            if(enroll != null)
            {
             
                bool validation =  await _context.SkipEligibilities.Where(x => x.FirstName== firstName)
                                                           .Any(t => t.LessThan3Payments == "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria1== "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria2== "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria3== "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria4== "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria5== "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria6== "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria7 == "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria8== "No"
                                                           && t.Criteria9== "No");                                                         
                                                                 
            }

            return elegible;


        }

        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        
    }
```

I will really appreciate any other suggestion or comments besides any possible solution to this issue. Thank you!

Comment: You can return `Task.FromResult(eligible)`

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic That makes the code compile but become nonsensical.  The whole point is that they're trying to perform the operation asynchronously.  If they want it to be synchronous, it should simply return a `bool` and not a task.

Comment: Sure, but this looks like just an example to me (e.g. `eligible` is not set anywhere). I understand that the idea is to have a method which call a few async methods internally and based on their results returns a boolean.

Comment: Correct @ZdeslavVojkovic . This is a method of a service I will inject later in one of my controllers, that's why it's not set anywhere. I will use it to validate a parameter in my HttpPost Create().